# OpenNLP splits our sentences in half along special characters

Tags: pdf, utf-8, special-characters, opennlp

We're facing an issue while processing text extracted from PDF documents (the content of which we do not have control over).
Most of our text data happen to have sections which pose a challenge for OpenNLP which we use for detecting sentences for further processing. We are using the *en-sent.bin* model file [from the OpenNLP website](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/).

For example, one can often encounter GPS coordinates like `40° 43.554’ N, 73° 59.814’ W` in these texts, where OpenNLP believes anything after a `’` character must belong to a new sentence.
This results in unwanted splitting of some of our sentences, for which we'd like to a find a solution or workaround.

The above character turns out not to be a regular single quote (`U+0027`), but one called *'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'* (`U+2019` or `0xE2 0x80 0x99` in hex). It looks like the sentence that contains the coordinates is split exactly along these.

We don't know how the *en-sent.bin* Sentence Detector model is trained or what character encoding it is working with (our input is UTF-8), as we found no such information in the documentation of OpenNLP (despite it mentioning that the character encoding to be used is specified during training of the model).

Filtering out such characters (i.e. all of those along which the splits happen) as a solution was dismissed, since we can't know for sure which ones are affected and it might also introduce the very similar problem of accidentally joining two sentences.

Since our team is highly inexperienced with OpenNLP, we're struggling to fix this. We have so far identified what we believe to be two candidate causes for the unwanted split, which I'd rather not post unless absolutely necessary, in order not to affect your thinking.

*Please note that I'm obliged not to include our source code or the exact data we're feeding as those are highly confidential and the latter may contain personal or otherwise protected information.*

Comment: The OpenNLP models available on that website are pretty generic and often performance can suffer as a result. Have you tried creating your own sentence model and using it? Could you normalize the text prior to sentence detection to substitute the coordinates with placeholders via a regex as to not affect the sentence detection?

Comment: @jbird Thanks for your suggestions! We did consider rolling our own model, but first we'd like to find out if we're missing something, so we decided to ask first.

Unfortunately we can't really do any such alterations to the text prior to feeding it into the detector as we don't know the contents up front. Also, there would be too many chunks to mask out with placeholders. The PDFs are stuff like documentations for certain facilities and others of similar complexity. Have lots of content that may be (is being?) considered garbage by the sentence detector that's actually part of a sentence.

Comment: +1 to jbird's suggestion of training your own model. I have never trained my own sentence model in opennlp, but trained several other components (tagger, NER model, etc.) and it's usually very easy. See https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.training

Comment: @Igor Thank you! We'll definitely discuss this possibility. Unfortunately, creating the training set seems to be a major challenge in our case, so we'll have to resolve that issue in case this is the best option to go by.